# JSON Data into DatagridView in VB.NET

Tags: json, vb.net, datagridview

I currently try to get my JSON Data into a DatagridView so it is in a reader-friendly format.
I use this to get my JSON String:

```
Dim Uri As New Uri("LINK")
Dim jsonString As String = "{ ""Version"": ""1"" }"
Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString)
Dim result_post = SendRequest(Uri, data, "application/json", "POST")
MsgBox(result_post)
```

This is what I get on the MsgBox

```
{
   "code":200,
   "status":"OK",
   "data":{
      "Catalog":[
         {
            "ItemId":"shield_level_5",
            "ItemClass":"shields",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Level 5 Shield",
            "Description":"Strong defense against projectile attacks",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":199,
               "VC":25
            },
            "RealCurrencyPrices":{
               "GBP":149,
               "EUR":169
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"energy_boost_1",
            "ItemClass":"boosts",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Energy Drink Six-Pack",
            "Description":"Get a quick burst of energy whenever you need it",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":199,
               "VC":25
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"required_item_for_grant_a_1",
            "ItemClass":"sets",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Grant Set Item 1",
            "Description":"Item 1 from the set of items needed to get Granted Item A for free",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":249,
               "VC":1500
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"required_item_for_grant_a_2",
            "ItemClass":"sets",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Grant Set Item 2",
            "Description":"Item 2 from the set of items needed to get Granted Item A for free",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":249,
               "VC":1500
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"required_item_for_grant_a_3",
            "ItemClass":"sets",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Grant Set Item 3",
            "Description":"Item 3 from the set of items needed to get Granted Item A for free",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":249,
               "VC":1500
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"required_item_for_grant_a_4",
            "ItemClass":"sets",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Grant Set Item 4",
            "Description":"Item 4 from the set of items needed to get Granted Item A for free",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":249,
               "VC":1500
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"granted_item_a",
            "ItemClass":"sets",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Granted Item A",
            "Description":"Bonus item granted for free once the full set of 4 Grant Set items are collected",
            "GrantedIfPlayerHas":[
               "required_item_for_grant_a_1",
               "required_item_for_grant_a_2",
               "required_item_for_grant_a_3",
               "required_item_for_grant_a_4"
            ]
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"consumable_item_1",
            "ItemClass":"Consumables",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Consumable Item 1",
            "Description":"Item demonstrating usage-based consumables",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "VC":500
            },
            "Consumable":{
               "UsageCount":3
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"consumable_item_2",
            "ItemClass":"Consumables",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Consumable Item 2",
            "Description":"Item demonstrating time-based consumables",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "VC":750
            },
            "Consumable":{
               "UsagePeriod":3600,
               "UsagePeriodGroup":"usage_group_1"
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"sub_bundle_item_1",
            "ItemClass":"Bundles",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Bundled Item 1",
            "Description":"Item which is added to the user inventory as part of a bundle"
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"sub_bundle_item_2",
            "ItemClass":"Bundles",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Bundled Item 2",
            "Description":"Item which is added to the user inventory as part of a bundle"
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"item_bundle_1",
            "ItemClass":"Bundles",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Item bundle 1",
            "Description":"Item which, when added to the user inventory, also adds other bundled items",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":599
            },
            "Bundle":{
               "BundledItems":[
                  "sub_bundle_item_1",
                  "sub_bundle_item_2"
               ],
               "BundledResultTables":[
                  "random_result_1"
               ],
               "BundledVirtualCurrencies":{
                  "VC":1000
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"key_item_1",
            "ItemClass":"Containers",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Key Item 1",
            "Description":"Key used to unlock Container 1",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":199
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"sub_container_item_1",
            "ItemClass":"Containers",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Container Item 1",
            "Description":"Item which is added to the user inventory as part of opening a container"
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"sub_container_item_2",
            "ItemClass":"Containers",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Container Item 2",
            "Description":"Item which is added to the user inventory as part of opening a container"
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"item_container_1",
            "ItemClass":"Containers",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Item Container 1",
            "Description":"Item which, when opened with Key Item 1, also adds the items it holds to the user inventory",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":499
            },
            "Consumable":{
               "UsageCount":1
            },
            "Container":{
               "KeyItemId":"key_item_1",
               "ItemContents":[
                  "sub_container_item_1",
                  "sub_container_item_2"
               ],
               "ResultTableContents":[
                  "random_result_1"
               ],
               "VirtualCurrencyContents":{
                  "VC":1000
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"item_container_2",
            "ItemClass":"Containers",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Item Container 2",
            "Description":"Item which, when opened (no key needed), adds the items it holds to the user inventory",
            "VirtualCurrencyPrices":{
               "RM":99
            },
            "Consumable":{
               "UsageCount":1
            },
            "Container":{
               "VirtualCurrencyContents":{
                  "VC":1000
               }
            }
         },
         {
            "ItemId":"starterpack_1",
            "ItemClass":"starterpacks",
            "CatalogVersion":"1",
            "DisplayName":"Super Starter Pack",
            "Description":"Everything you need to get started fast track at the right price"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Now, I want to get the data of each item in the JSON String into a DatagridView which looks like this:

[image: http://i.epvpimg.com/5i9ug.png]

I tried using

```
Dim obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_result)(result_post)
```

but I don't know how to continue further and loop each item in the string. When I try to get items out directly the string it is empty.

I hope someone can help me.

Greetz,
Kia.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the answer is always with the same format you can use the library

***Newtonsoft.Json.Linq*** to trabsform the string into a JSONObject and the intern JSONArray.
Then you will have a JSONObject with 2 "Strings" (code and status) and a JSONArray (data).

Then with this you can create a class with the Public Properties: Id, Name, Description, VC_Price and RM_Price. Where you put the info from the JSONArray into those, and those into a ***BindingList(Of thatClass)***

And then you simply pass the BlindingList to the DataGridView DataSource like this: ***table1.DataSource = bindingList1***

have you understood me?

Answer (score 0):

try this you can use current API

```
Dim request As HttpWebRequest
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = Nothing
Dim api As String = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"
Try
    request = DirectCast(WebRequest.Create(api), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim WebClient = New WebClient
    response = DirectCast(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Dim result As String = WebClient.DownloadString(api)
    'MsgBox(result)
    Dim Results() = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of GetTest())(result)
    tb = New DataTable
    For Each items As GetTest In Results
        'dataholder += String.Format("{0}:{1} ,", items.Name)
        'tb.Rows(0)(0) = items.Name
        DataGridView1.Rows.Add(items.Name)
        'MsgBox()
    Next
    'dataholder = dataholder.Remove(dataholder.Length - 2)

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
End Try
```